# Trouble understanding constrained ordination in Redundancy analysis (RDA) with vegan package

Tags: r, vegan, rda

Following the suggestion of a reviewer, I am analysing functional traits data using a Redundancy analysis (RDA). This is the first time that I am using this method so I am having some trouble understanding its subtilities.

My data have the following structure :

```
# Generate a dataset of 7 traits for 27 individuals
traits_test <- as.data.frame(matrix(data = 0, ncol = 7, nrow = 27))
colnames(traits_test) <- paste(array("trait_", dim = 7), c(1:7), sep = "")
for(i in 1:7) traits_test[,i] <- runif(27, 0, 1)

# Generate a dataframe with 3 factors
factor1 <- as.factor(c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A","B", "B", "B", "B", "A", 
                       "A", "A", "A", "A", "B","B", "B", "B", "A", "A", 
                       "A", "A", "A", "B","B", "B", "B"))
factor2 <- as.factor(c(array("C", dim = 9), array("D", dim = 18)))
factor3 <- as.factor(c(array("E", dim = 9), array("F", dim = 9), array("G", dim = 9)))
varexp <- cbind.data.frame(factor1, factor2, factor3)
```

The first step of my study was to analyse each traits with the following mixed model :

```
trait_x ~ factor1 + factor2 + (1|factor3)
```

The second step is to use a multivariate approch with a RDA. As I didn't know how to include random effects in RDA, I coded the 3rd factor as a normal factor  with the following model (that gave my satisfying results) :

```
# Analysis conducted with the vegan package
library(vegan)

# RDA analysis
RDA <- rda(traits_test ~ factor1 + factor2 + factor3, data = varexp)
```

However, I was suggested by the reviewer to code the 3rd factor as a covariate with the following model :

```
RDA <- rda(traits_test ~ factor1 + factor2 + Condition(factor3), data = varexp)
```

What I don't understand is that in this last model, I have in the output only 1 RDA axis instead of 3 in the initial model. Could somebody explain to me exactly what does it mean to include a factor as Conditional and is it really the equivalent of a random effect ?

Thanks to anyone who can help !

Answer (score 0):

This means that some terms of `~ factor1 + factor2` were *aliased* when you first had `factor3`. "Aliased" means about the same as being synonymous. That is, when you know the values of `factor3`, you also know the values of either `factor1` or `factor2`. These do not add any new information to the model where you already have `factor3`. You also got a message of this saying that some terms were aliased.

To see which terms were aliased, issue with your result object `RDA`

```
alias(RDA) # long display
alias(RDA, names = TRUE) # give only the names of aliased terms
```